# yii menu dependiente

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Tengo problemas para hacer un menu dependiente, el problema que tengo es que solo me toma los datos de un menu y el otro toma todos los valores por defecto.

Esta es la funcion de mi controlador

```
public function actionAjaxResultados(){
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
                if (isset($_POST['id_establecimiento'])) {

                    $idEstablecimiento = $_POST['id_establecimiento'];
                    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), 'Todos');
                    $departamentos = Departamento::model()->findAll('id_establecimiento =:establecimiento', array(':establecimiento' => $idEstablecimiento));
                    $edificios = Edificio::model()->findAll('id_establecimiento =:establecimiento', array(':establecimiento' => $idEstablecimiento));



                    foreach($edificios as $edificio ){

                        //$resultado = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $departamentos->id), CHtml::encode($departamentos->nombre));  
                        $resultado1 = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $edificio->id), CHtml::encode($edificio->nombre));
                        echo CJSON::encode(array('edificio' => $resultado1));
                        //var_dump($resultado);
                    }

                    foreach($departamentos as $departamento ){

                        $resultado2 = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $departamento->id), CHtml::encode($departamento->nombre));
                        //$resultado = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $edificio->id), CHtml::encode($edificio->nombre));
                        echo CJSON::encode(array('departamento' => $resultado2));
                        //var_dump($resultado);
                    }
                    /*
                        echo CJSON::encode(array(
                          'edificio'=>$resultado1,
                          'departamento'=>$resultado2,
                      ));

                     */
                }
            }
        }
```

Lo comentado son intentos de hacer algo

Este es el admin

```
  array(
        'name' => 'id_establecimiento',
        'value' => '$data->establecimiento->nombre',
        'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'id_establecimiento',
            CHtml::listData($establecimiento, 'id', 'nombre'),
            array(
                'empty' => 'Todos',
                /* 'ajax' => array(
                                 'type' => 'POST',
                                 'url' => CController::createUrl('equipo/ajaxResultados'),
                                 'data' => array('id_establecimiento' => 'js:this.value'),
                                 'update' => '#Equipo_id_departamento',
                 )*/

                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('equipo/ajaxResultados'),
                    'data' => array('id_establecimiento' => 'js:this.value'),
                    'update' => '#Equipo_id_edificio',
                    'update' => '#Equipo_id_departamento'
                    /*'success'=>"function(){ 
                         $('#Requerimiento_id_edificio').html(edificio);
                         $('#Requerimiento_id_departamento').html(departamento);

                     }",*/

                )
            )),
```